# Azure - Unable to create MethodHandles to use Java 9+ MethodHandles.privateLookupIn

Tags: java, azure

Im using azure-storage-blob library to upload file to Azure,but when running the code Im getting the below warning. Please assist how to solve this warning.

```
[main] INFO com.azure.core.implementation.ReflectionUtils - Unable to create MethodHandles to use Java 9+ MethodHandles.privateLookupIn. Will attempt to fallback to using the package-private constructor.
```

Code used:

```
        final String STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;"+ "AccountName="+Name+";"
                    + "AccountKey="+Key+";EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
        BlobServiceClient  blobServiceClient = new  BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING).buildClient();
        BlobContainerClient  containerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient(containerName);
        String  localPath = "target/"+filename+".json";
        BlobClient  blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(filename+".json");
        logger.info("\nUploading to Blob storage as blob:\n\t" + blobClient.getBlobUrl());
        blobClient.uploadFromFile(localPath);
```

Pom.xml:

```
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.azure/azure-storage-blob -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
            <version>12.22.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Please provide your code

Answer (score 0):

> [main] INFO com.azure.core.implementation.ReflectionUtils - Unable to create MethodHandles to use Java 9+ MethodHandles.privateLookupIn. Will attempt to fallback to using the package-private constructor.

This error could be due to version incompatibility. Try upgrading or downgrading version of your dependencies.

Follow the below steps upload file to Azure Storage account:

**Code Snippet:**

- Below is the Java code to upload to file to storage account

```java
package com.blobs.quickstart;

import com.azure.identity.*;
import com.azure.storage.blob.*;
import com.azure.storage.blob.models.*;
import java.io.*;

public class App
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        String connectStr = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=kpstracnt;AccountKey=dtYi50F/d/on91jffurZ8Dhr2/sgRJVnO1Tj420YrS27Cc8p/umgjOWhnYAqlkKnme20P0CElPWS+ASteGDoTQ==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
        .connectionString(connectStr)
        .buildClient();
        String containerName = "blob" + java.util.UUID.randomUUID();
        BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.createBlobContainer(containerName);
        String localPath = "./datafile/";
        String fileName = "blobfile" + java.util.UUID.randomUUID() + ".txt";
        BlobClient blobClient = blobContainerClient.getBlobClient(fileName);
        FileWriter writer = null;
        try
        {
            writer = new FileWriter(localPath + fileName, true);
            writer.write("Hello, Pravallika!");
            writer.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("\nUploading file to Azure Blob storage:\n\t" + blobClient.getBlobUrl());
        blobClient.uploadFromFile(localPath + fileName);   
    }
}
```

**pom.xml:**

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.blobs.quickstart</groupId>
  <artifactId>blob-quickstart</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>blob-quickstart</name>
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
      <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
      <version>12.22.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
       <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
       <version>1.7.2</version>
       <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
       <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Run `mvn clean install`

[image]
[image]

Run the application with command: `mvn exec:java -D exec.mainClass=com.blobs.quickstart.App -D exec.cleanupDaemonThreads=false` :

**Response:**

[image]

**References:**

[Azure Blob Storage library - Java](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-java?tabs=powershell%2Cmanaged-identity%2Croles-azure-portal%2Csign-in-azure-cli)

Comment: Hi @pravallika-kv , Im using the same code as above. But the azure-storage-blob version Im using is 12.22.2. This warning happens only from last week. Im not sure what might be the root cause..

Comment: Can you try with 12.22.0? Use the same `pom.xml` which I have given

Comment: hi, I tried upgrading and downgrading still same warning

Comment: Did you try with the code I have given?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the question as well

Comment: I tried with [12.22.2](https://i.imgur.com/eHBBfrB.png) as well and it worked for me. Try using `Java 17` and create a new project and use the code and `pom.xml` which I have given above.

Comment: @Vinoth, Did it work or are you still facing the issue?

Comment: Im using Java 8, maybe it could be Java issue. I will upgrade java and let you know

Comment: yes it worked. Updated the Java to latest version. Thanks